# VB.NET wait for command line input before continuing

Tags: vb.net, command-line, process

I'm writing a program to interface with an inspection machine. The machine has the ability to output command lines during its program run.

The machine has an interface application which allows the passing and automatic start of programs into the machine. I can get this to work with a single instance, however I would like to be able to select several programs for it to run back to back.

Below is the code to pass a single program to the machine:

```
im ProgramName As String = cbProgram.Text
    Dim ProgURL = GetXMLNode(1, ProgramName)

    Dim exeDir As New IO.FileInfo(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.FullName)

    Dim EXEPath = IO.Path.Combine(exeDir.DirectoryName, "iscmd.exe")


    ' New ProcessStartInfo created
    Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo

    ' Specify the location of the binary
    p.FileName = EXEPath

    ' Use these arguments for the process
    p.Arguments = " /run""" & ProgURL & """ /nowait"

    ' Use a hidden window
    p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

    ' Start the process
    Dim ISCMD As Process = Process.Start(p)
    ISCMD.WaitForExit()
    MsgBox("PING!")
```

The `PING` will show immediately after the program has been passed to the machine (but not completed). What I want to be able to do is build an array of programs and launch this process once each time a program has completed. Is it possible to use a command line from the machine to signal to my software that the next program can be started? Below is a screenshot the machines command line.

[image: ScreenShot of the Machine command line interface]

Comment: You won't be able to achieve this if `ISCMD.WaitForExit()` is not blocking until the process exits. Is the process actually running or does it start some work and exit, while the work continues in another process?

Comment: The process starts, passes the execution to the software, and then exits - hence which the WaitForExit does not pause the subroutine. The ISCMD.exe is very simple and takes very little time but the program which it runs on the machine will take a few minutes. At the end of this program i want to send some sort of signal from the machine back to my subroutine so it can start another program and repeat the process.

At the end of the machine program i can launch a command line as shown in the picture. Is there any way to do this with a command line?